# Serverless Framework Instrumentation not creating spans for DynamoDB queries using AWS SDK DynamoDB client when imported directly

Tags: serverless-framework, dashboard, instrumentation

I am seeing that the serverless instrumentation that occurs during package phase does not instrument database queries to dynamodb using the aws sdk when the dynamodb client is imported through
const DynamoDb = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb')" but is instrumented when imported through
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')"

I see span details for a lambda invocation when importing the entire AWS SDK but not when importing just the dynamodb client.

Importing the Dynamodb client and not the entire AWS SDK is a best practice to reduce cold starts due to module initialization time.

I would prefer not to include the Serverless SDK as a dependency packaged in the Lambda where I could use the custom span event logging for this database query timing as that increases the lambda deployable size.

Any suggestions to get this default instrumentation during package phase when importing only the DynamoDB Client?

I am using serverless version 2.72.3.

Thank you

Using DynamoDB client by importing entire AWS SDK

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

...

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const dbclient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

...

const data = await ddb.query(params).promise();
```

[image]

Using DynamoDB client by importing only the dynamodb client

```
const Dynamodb = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

...

const config = { region: 'us-east-1', }; 
const dbclient = Dynamodb.DocumentClient(config);

...

const data = await this.db.query(params).promise();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Serverless Framework support and they mentioned that it is by design so that the instrumentation can happen once over the entire SDK instead of potentially multiple times. They do not appear to have plans to improve their design at this time.

A proposed solution from Serverless Framework support is to use their Serverless Cloud offering which is a rework of the Serverless Console found at console.serverless.com.

Words from Serverless Framework support about Serverless Cloud "It's designed for folks who want a lot more info about their deployed services and is way easier to integrate as it directly attaches to the AWS account and not the individual services deployed with an SDK. All instrumentation is activated browser-side instead of relying on a client-side package process."